# (WordPress) Trying to generate a dynamic button, on a slider using Advance Custom Fields plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, advanced-custom-fields

So I'm putting together a custom theme and a part of the theme is an option for a user to be able to choose the background for a slide on the homepage slider, the content in the slide, and the number of slides in the slideshow. I'm using Advance custom fields plugin for this, and one of the fields is a label for a button called  `slide_button_label`.

I put together some simple code to check to see if a user put any value in the field, if they did then it will display the button with whatever text they put for the label, if no value was entered then the button simply won't appear.

```
<?php if (the_field('slide_button_label')) { ?>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn--frontpage">
        <?php the_field('slide_button_label') ?>
    </a>
 <?php } ?>
```

It works mostly but a weird issue I'm having is when the button does show up the `a tag`, and class that was attached to gets completely removed and it just shows the plain text. I'm at a loss to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use change "the_field" function in if statement. Use get_field instead:

```php
<?php if (get_field('slide_button_label')) { ?>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn--frontpage">
        <?php the_field('slide_button_label') ?>
    </a>
 <?php } ?>
```

get_field return a value but the_field display a value.

Comment: Thanks, I keep getting "the_field" and "get_field" mixed up.

Comment: It is always the same logic in WordPress: `the_ID()` and `get_the_ID()`  or `the_title()` and `get_the_title()`